# What to do with insects in my house?

Tags: dua, creatures

I have entomophobia (it is the phobia fear of insects) and I cannot go into a room that has an insect in it until the insect is discarded. This phobia is actually serious as I always shake and sometimes cry when I see an insect. If the insect was in my room I would not fall asleep even after someone got rid of it for me.

I know that in Islam we cannot harm or kill animals but I feel guilty because I always tell someone to come and 'get rid of the insect' since I can't do it myself (because of my phobia).

Is it ok to kill the insect inside my house because I have entomophobia and if I don't it will hurt me (by biting me)?

Is there some duas I can say to prevent insects or any creatures from entering my house?

Any other help and advice I should know.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assalm o Alaikum
Islam allowed us to kill harmful insects... But remember that the Holy prophet P.B.U.H has told to kill such insects in a good manner which means in once,not by torturing.
Jzk